# How do I make my query avoid the "single-row subquery returns more than one row" error

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

I need to return the titles of books that are most frequently purchased. If multiple books are purchased the same amount then I receive the error:

```
SELECT title
FROM books JOIN orderitems
USING (isbn) WHERE isbn=
    (SELECT isbn
    FROM orderitems
    HAVING SUM (quantity) =
        (SELECT MAX(SUM(quantity))
        FROM orderitems
        GROUP BY isbn)
    GROUP BY isbn)
GROUP BY title;
```

Comment: Change `WHERE isbn=` to `WHERE isbn IN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you sub-query return multiple row which not support = operator so i used `in`

```
SELECT title
FROM books JOIN orderitems
USING (isbn) WHERE isbn in
    (SELECT isbn
    FROM orderitems
    group by isbn
    HAVING SUM (quantity) =
        (SELECT MAX(SUM(quantity))
        FROM orderitems
        GROUP BY isbn
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions!

```
SELECT title
FROM (SELECT isbn, title, SUM(quantity) as quantity,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM books b JOIN
           orderitems oi
           USING (isbn)
      GROUP BY isbn, title
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to rank the books by order quantity and only show the book(s) ranked highest (rank #1 for the greatest quantity) . There is the window function `RANK` for ranking rows.

You want to select the book title only, so select the title from books and apply your criteria in a `WHERE` clause.

```
select title
from books
where (isbn, 1) in -- ISBN ranked #1
(
  select isbn, rank() over (order by sum(quantity) desc)
  from orderitems
  group by isbn
);
```